# How do I call Mix_GetError from the nim SDL2 Mixer bindings?

Tags: sdl-2, nim-lang, sdl-mixer

There are multiple references in the nim SDL2 [mixer.nim](https://github.com/nim-lang/sdl2/blob/master/src/sdl2/mixer.nim) file to
`Error messages can be retrieved from Mix_GetError().`

However, I can't seem to find this function defined in the mixer.nim file

How can I get the latest error string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `sdl2.getError()` (from from the base [sdl2 bindings](https://github.com/nim-lang/sdl2/blob/master/src/sdl2.nim#L1588)) to get the latest error string.

Comment: that's not a problem with the documentation in sdl2 mixer bindings. Those comments were directly copied from the original SDL_mixer documentation, and it clearly says to use Mix_GetError. It just so happens that `Mix_GetError` is actually an alias for SDL's own GetError so it works, but it would still be better to call Mix_GetError specifically for errors with SDL_mixer. See https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_mixer/blob/main/include/SDL_mixer.h#L701